# Merge multiple column having comma separated values to a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has three columns

[image]

I want my result set to be like

[image]

Comment: which version of sql-server are you using ?

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: But i need to have from multiple column as well

Comment: just concatenate all the 3 columns and use the answer from duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You need to split the strings. [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

If you are on Sql Server 2016 you can use the built in `String_Split()`: [Splitting Strings: SQL Server 2016 To The Rescue!](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/03/splitting-strings-sql-server-2016-rescue/)

Comment: My favorite Split string function for older versions  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: Ahh yes, there was a bunch of drama around Moden's split when Aaron modified it for his testing in [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings). They went so far as to shut down the comments on that post forever. I agree it is still it's a good option to have, though!